# Find all primes $p$, such that $p^p+2$ is also prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Find all primes $p$ such that $$p^p+2$$ is also prime

I have been struggling with this problem the past few days and I can't seem to figure a way around it. I conjecture that the only solution is $p=3$. Hence my first approach was $mod\ 3$ and contradiction, which didn't lead me far, as the cases $p\equiv 0,1\pmod{3}$ conclude that either $p=3$ or $p^p+2=3$, a contradiction. But the case: $$p \equiv -1\pmod{3}\Leftrightarrow\ p^p+2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$ doesn't help me deduce something and I don't know how to continue on with this case. I have also proved that $$p^p+2\equiv 1\pmod{6},\forall\ p>3, p\equiv -1\pmod{3}$$ which I also can't seem to find useful. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Note:  contrary to the claim in the post, $p\equiv 1 \pmod 6\implies p^p+2\equiv 3\pmod 6$.

Comment: @Vepir  It's not a great duplicate since there is no answer provided.  The posted "solutions" provide some numerical evidence and some heuristic arguments, but there is no resolution there that I can see.

Comment: @lulu when $p\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ then you can easily deduct $p\equiv -1\pmod{6}$ and as such $p^p+2\equiv 1\pmod{6}$

Comment: You made the claim that $p^p+2\equiv 1 \pmod 6\,\forall\, p>3$.  This claim is false.  The claim is false for $p=7$, for example...indeed it is false for every prime $p\equiv 1 \pmod 6$.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear enough with my phrasing. I edited my post.